# Microsoft Sync Framework SqlServerCE to Custom DBConnection Not Catching Errors/Cleaning Up Changes

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce, ibm-mq, microsoft-sync-framework

Forgive my ignorance with Microsoft Sync Framework as I am pretty new to it. But anyway, I am attempting to develop a custom Upload Only sync process from Sql CE to a custom InsertCommand derived class that interfaces with IBM websphere MQ.

```
    public class MyServerSyncProvider : DbServerSyncProvider
{
            #region Constructors

    public MyServerSyncProvider()
    {
        base.Connection = CreateConnection();
        base.SyncAdapters.Add(MySyncAdapter);
    }
}
   class MySyncAdapter : SyncAdapter
{
    public MySyncAdapter(DbServerSyncProvider syncProvider)
    {
        base.TableName = "MyTable";

        base.InsertCommand = SyncHelper.CreateStoredProcCommand(syncProvider.Connection, "Queue Message Start:");

        var parm1 = base.InsertCommand.CreateParameter();
        parm1.ParameterName = "@parm1";
        parm1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parm1.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
        parm1.SourceColumn = "source_column";
        base.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(parm1);

        /////More Input parms

        var rowCount = base.InsertCommand.CreateParameter();
        rowCount.ParameterName = "@sync_row_count";
        rowCount.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        rowCount.DbType = DbType.Int16;
        rowCount.SourceColumn = Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SyncSession.SyncRowCount;
        base.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(rowCount);

    }
}
```

This is accomplished by overwriting the ExecuteNonQuery Method to write to a Queue (we create the message from the command text/parameters).

```
    Public Overrides Function ExecuteNonQuery() As Integer

    Dim mqConnectionObject As MQServerConnection = DirectCast(Me.Connection, MQServerConnection)
    ''get an instance of the MQServerFacade
    Dim mqServerFacade As MQTEPServerFacade = DirectCast(Me.Connection, MQServerConnection).MQServer
    If Me.Timeout > 0 Then
        mqServerFacade.Timeout = Me.Timeout
    End If
    Me.Parameters("@sync_row_count").Value = 0
    Try
        mqServerFacade.PutOnRequestQueue(CreateXmlDocumentForMQMessage())
        Me.Parameters("@sync_row_count").Value = 1
        Return 1
    Catch ex As Exception
        _logger.Write(TraceEventType.[Error], ex.Message)
        Return -1
    End Try
End Function
```

Oddly enough, this is all working. When synchronizing, the ApplyChanges function is creating a new MQ 'connection'. It then iterates through each row in the change set, fills in the parameters properly and puts the message on the queue. (FYI the sync process grabs all rows in the client table and then deletes the rows after the sync finishes. No anchors I think are needed.)

The problem I am having is that it is not completely tracking the changes properly. For example, any error that could potentially occur on the Insert process is not caught.  As you can see in the sample above, I have to enclose the transaction in a try block or else the sync would stop completely. I was expecting to have the error caught and then have the process hit the ApplyChangeFailed listener and then go on to the next row (see below).

```
    public class MySynchronizationService : DbSyncProviderService<MyServerSyncProvider>
{
    private static readonly string category = "MySynchronizationService";

    public MySynchronizationService()
    {
        this._serverSyncProvider.ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.ApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(_serverSyncProvider_ApplyChangeFailed);
    }

    void _serverSyncProvider_ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.ApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Action = Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.ApplyAction.Continue;
    }


    public override Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SyncContext ApplyChanges(Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SyncGroupMetadata groupMetaData, System.Data.DataSet changeSet, Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SyncSession syncSession)
    {
        SetupContext(category, "ApplyChanges");
        Logger.Write(TraceEventType.Information, string.Format("Applying changes for {0} synchronization group",groupMetaData.GroupName));
        return base.ApplyChanges(groupMetaData, changeSet, syncSession);
    }
}
```

I heard that the @sync_row_count parameter had something to do with this but it does not seem to be doing anything. My try catch does prevent the row from being put on to the queue but I do not get any feedback (syncStatistics just says that all rows were applied successfully).

Additionally, the sync process is on a timer and on the next go through, it attempts to sync the same rows from the previous batch. Luckily the row state is set to 'Added' so my ExecuteNonQuery is not called again for these rows. This just further solidifies that there is some disconnect going on with inserting the data (putting on the queue) and how Microsoft Sync Framework tracks changes/errors.

Any assistance you all can provide will be appreciated. I know that this solution is kind of 'out of the box' since Microsoft Sync Framework as far as I can tell is usually DB to DB or File to File (and IBM MQ is obviously not a DB) but as stated above the process is 'working' but I obviously do not feel completely comfortable with what I implemented.

Comment: if you're grabbing all the rows from source, why do you have to use Sync Fx? why not simply read the table directly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JuneT. This functionality is a small piece of a huge project and the deadline for completion was very strict so I used the code from the other syncs in the same project to implement this MQ sync. I think that I have a solution by just overriding ApplyChanges which I will as an answer later.